# AngularJs Dynamic Filter Based on Selected Column

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am an AngularJs beginner , I have a json object

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "ASP.net",
    "description": "ASP.net Course",
    "cost": 3000,
    "areaId": 1,
    "addedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0751079",
    "deleted": false,
    "modifiedDate": "2017-12-11T15:36:32.0780015",
    "area": {
      "id": 1,
      "areaName": "Programming",
      "areaDescription": "Software Development Courses",
      "addedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0744734",
      "deleted": false,
      "modifiedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0746376"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "PHP",
    "description": "PHP Tutorial",
    "cost": 3000,
    "areaId": 1,
    "addedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0751088",
    "deleted": false,
    "modifiedDate": "2017-12-14T12:41:06.8059371",
    "area": {
      "id": 1,
      "areaName": "Programming",
      "areaDescription": "Software Development Courses",
      "addedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0744734",
      "deleted": false,
      "modifiedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0746376"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "JAVA",
    "description": "JAVA Tutorial",
    "cost": 3000,
    "areaId": 1,
    "addedDate": "2017-12-05T10:28:59.5280719",
    "deleted": false,
    "modifiedDate": "2017-12-05T10:28:59.5280713",
    "area": {
      "id": 1,
      "areaName": "Programming",
      "areaDescription": "Software Development Courses",
      "addedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0744734",
      "deleted": false,
      "modifiedDate": "2017-11-29T16:58:57.0746376"
    }
  }]
```

and simple HTML table with filter input

```
  <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="label label-primary" style="font-size:large"> Search By :</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select ng-model="app.queryByValue" class="dropdown form-control input-sm" id="ddlseach">
                            <option ng-repeat="x in app.queryByDll" ng-value="x.id">{{x.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class='wrapper'>
                            <input ng-model="app.query[app.queryByValue]" class="input-sm form-control" id="txtsrch1" placeholder=" -- Search --" />
                            <!--<input ng-model="app.query.area.areaName" class="input-sm form-control" id="txtsrch2" placeholder=" -- Search --" style="visibility:hidden" />-->
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

    <table class="table  table-condensed">
                    <tr style="cursor:pointer">
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'id'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Id
                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='id',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='id',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='id'}"></i>
                        </th>

                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'area.areaName'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Area
                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='area.areaName',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='area.areaName',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='area.areaName'}"></i>
                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Name

                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='name',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='name',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='name'}"></i>

                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'description'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Description

                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='description',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='description',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='description'}"></i>

                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'cost'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Cost
                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='cost',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='cost',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='cost'}"></i>
                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'modifiedDate'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Last Modified Date

                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='modifiedDate',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='modifiedDate',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='modifiedDate'}"></i>
                        </th>
                        <th ng-click="predicate = 'deleted'; reverse=!reverse">
                            Deleted ?

                            <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='deleted',
                                      'fa fa-arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='deleted',
                                      'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='deleted'}"></i>
                        </th>
                        <th colspan="3"><center>Action</center></th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr dir-paginate="c in app.courses |  orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:app.query | itemsPerPage:app.pageRecords">
                        <td>{{ c.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ c.area.areaName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ c.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ c.description }}</td>
                        <td>{{ c.cost }}</td>
                        <td><span ng-bind="c.modifiedDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'"></span> </td>
                        <td><span ng-bind="c.deleted"></span> </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm " value="Update" ng-click="app.UpdateCourse(c)" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Soft Delete" ng-click="app.DeleteCourse(c,'soft')" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="Hard Delete" ng-click="app.DeleteCourse(c,'hard')" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

And finally JS code

```
 $http.get(WepAPI_URL).then(function (response) {
            vm.courses = response.data;
            vm.queryByDll =
                [
                    {
                        'id': '$', 'name': 'All'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': 'id', 'name': 'ID'
                    },
                    {
                        'id':'area.areaName', 'name': 'Area'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': 'name', 'name': 'Name'
                    }, {
                        'id': 'description', 'name': 'Description'
                    }
                    , {
                        'id': 'cost', 'name': 'Cost'
                    }];
            vm.queryByValue = vm.queryByDll[0].id;

            vm.pageRecords = 5;
        });
```

Data displayed successfully on the table and i am able to filter the object with all fields except " area.areaName "

so the following line is worked for all fields except the child object [AREA]

```
<input ng-model="app.query[app.queryByValue]" class="input-sm form-control" id="txtsrch1" placeholder=" -- Search --" />
```

However , when i use this line

```
<input ng-model="app.query.area.areaName" class="input-sm form-control" id="txtsrch2" placeholder=" -- Search --" />
```

filtering with area works fine

I have made a workaround by using the 2 textboxes and when user select Area , I show txtsrch2 and  hide txtsrch1

but i am sure  there is a better solution the let me filter with all fields including the child object using one text box

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is that the `area.areaName` element is the only filter criteria listed two levels deep.  So in your first filter attempt using `app.query[app.queryByValue]` you actually end up trying to filter on `app.query["area.areaName"]` which will not interpret the value you desire.

Based on your table rendering, I am going to assume that each object in your response will only have one `area` object nested inside of it (e.g., your JSON shows area as an array within each response object, but your table rendering assumes there is only one such area object).  If this assumption is correct, then there are two ways you can fix your problem:

1. Modify your JSON response to put `areaName` as a top-level property in each response object when returned from server and then just use `areaName` in the filter condition

OR

2. Post-process the JSON response when received to copy `areaName` from inside the `area` array back to a top-level property in the response object and then just use `areaName` in the filter condition

I hope one of these solutions is feasible for you to implement.

Comment: Many thanks Mr.David , you are right , moving areaName to top level will make it looks like the other properties and it will  solve the problem , however i need a way to filter areaName without moving it to top level , is that possible ? suppose that i have many child objects and i want to keep each property in its own place :/